# How to use own icons in Flet

Tags: icons, load, assets, flet

I can't find how to load my own icons in Flet.

I'm testing Flet with the intention of making a desktop app (pure desktop, not Internet needed), but I'm not able to use my own icons to begin with. I can only use the ones that come inside ft.icons, but I'd rather use my own by loading them from a folder similar to /assets/icons. Can I do that? How?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, I don't see a way of doing this; however, you could use the `Image` class instead.

I would suggest you create an assets folder under your main project folder.

Let's assume you have the following folder structure on your project:

```
/assets
   /icons/my-icon.png
main.py
```

When you are running your app, you should provide that folder to the initializer in the following way:

```
flet.app(target=YourApp(), assets_dir="assets")
```

Then you can access your images there directly and create an Image instance in the following way:

```
test_image = flet.Image(src="icons/my-icon.png", width=32, height=32, tooltip="Image Tooltip")
```

You can nest these Image controls inside of anything you want, so you have a lot of flexibility.

The only downside of doing it this way is if you are using light/dark themes on your app. Compared to the `Icon` class, you will have to specify the light/dark theme versions yourself and update them manually when you are switching your theme.

Here is the [official documentation](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/image/)

Comment: Works. Here an example:

add_img = Image(src='add.png', width=32, height=32, tooltip='Suma 1')
add_button = ElevatedButton(
        width=60, 
        height=40,
        on_click=plus_click, 
        content=Row([add_img], alignment=flet.MainAxisAlignment.SPACE_AROUND))

Although I would prefer to have an on_click event on the image and it would save me the button.